# Best way to split computation too large to fit into memory?

Tags: memory-management, tensorflow

I have an operation that's running out of memory when using a batch size greater than 4 (I normally run with 32). I thought I could be clever by splitting this one operation along the batch dimension, using `tf.split`, running it on a subset of the batch, and then recombining using `tf.concat`. For some reason this doesn't work and results in an OOM error. Just to be clear, if I run on a batch size of 4 it works without splitting. If instead I run on a batch size of 32, and even if I were to perform a 32-way split so that each individual element is run independently, I still run out of memory. Doesn't TF schedule separate operations so that they do not overwhelm the memory? If not do I need to explicitly set up some sort of conditional dependence?

Comment: Who is telling you that you are running out of memory? Is TF complaining, segfault, are you monitoring? Within TF, they currently don't check https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/threadpool_device_factory.cc#L26 and just set a large upper limit https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/threadpool_device_factory.cc#L40. I am sure they could appreciate you fixing it and submitting a pull request ;)

Comment: TF is throwing an OOM error. This is actually all on the GPU, so I'm not sure if the pages you linked to are relevant?

Comment: There's no memory awareness in the placer/scheduler in 0.10, so TensorFlow will try to run your ops in parallel even after splitting. Using smaller batch-size seems like the most natural way to splitting the work into chunks small enough to fit in memory

Comment: No, those pages aren't relevant. TF does try to handle memory for GPUs, but I am not an expert on this. I vote for shrinking the batch size. Were you able to do this previously with other code with a larger batch size? TF may have unseen overhead

Comment: Yes I can run the rest of the net with a batch size of 32 (or even 128), it's just this one op. More importantly, it's not even that compute intensive so I really wouldn't want to decrease the batch size just because of it. It's a minor op in the grand scheme of things, but just happens to be memory-intensive. @YaroslavBulatov, is there any way to prevent TF from parallelizing it?

Comment: You can force ops to run in sequence by running them in two different session.run calls, one after another. Also you can use tf.control_dependencies to serialize them in a single run call

Comment: @aidan.plenert.macdonald I didn't mean to imply that I could run this before using a different framework. I'm working exclusively in TF. It's just the addition of this op that's changed things.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, I currently use a for loop to iteratively go through the batch, and so I set it up so that each iteration of the for loop depends on the output of the previous one. It still doesn't work, and I think the reason is because during the gradient calculation it's running out of memory. I take it that the gradient calculation doesn't respect the conditional dependencies, right? How to deal with that?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov do you think something like TensorArray would be the right approach here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that the functional ops, specifically `map_fn` in this case, address my needs. By setting the `parallel_iterations` option to 1 (or some small number that would make the computation fit in memory), I'm able to control the degree of parallelism and avoid running out of memory.